# Rails Newsletter System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

In my app I want to build a basic newsletter system, but I wonder if there is any gem or plugin that makes this job easier.

Do you guys know anything that is reliable?

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)?

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#ruby